# How to stop the programming language part from updating?

Tags: update

I am using the latest Raspbian and I am not a programmer. Therefore, I don't want the programming part of Raspbian. Does this part get updated every time Raspbian updates? How can I stop the programming module from updating, so that I can save precious mobile data usage? It should not affect the other software after the programming section is removed or prevented from updating.

Comment: I think you are making a big mistake looking at things this way.  If you are not a programmer, it will be too easy to confuse things that may appear to be "just for programming" with things that are in fact crucial to some normal user functionality.  Remember, it is *all programs and programming* that make it go.  The base install does not include much clutter this way as it is intended that programmers have to do the work of installing the tools they want, not that normal users need do the work of uninstalling them.

Answer (score 1):

It is not safe to remove programming languages and stop future updates without disrupting current applications and opening your device to future unexpected failures.

Languages like python are implicitly used by a significant number of applications, also, many packages are distributed (partially) in source code form that need compile to installation on your device (gcc, g++) .

What you can do is to do check what is available for 'upgrade' and manually update modules that you consider important (at your own 'risk'):

```
$ apt-get update
...
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/rpi Translation-en
Fetched 7,015 kB in 43s (160 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
```

now, request the 'upgrade' but answer **n** on *Do you want to continue [Y/n]?*

```
$ apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  firmware-atheros firmware-brcm80211 firmware-libertas firmware-ralink firmware-realtek 
  libxapian22 libxml2 locales multiarch-support php5 php5-cli php5-common php5-mysql samba-common smbclient tzdata
xx upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 38.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 4,692 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? n
Abort.
```

Assume you want just to 'upgrade' the module tzdata

```
$ apt-get install tzdata
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
   tzdata
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 32 not upgraded.
Need to get 453 kB of archives.
After this operation, 13.3 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main tzdata all 2016d-0+deb7u1 [453 kB]
Fetched 453 kB in 1s (315 kB/s)
...
```

*pd: sudo required, omitted for brevity*

Comment: You will definitely FUBAR the system without python and perl, but I think using proper "uninstall/purge" methods should make that very clear (I think `apt` itself has a perl and/or python dependency).  Put another way **Do not remove perl or python or prevent upgrades on them.**  A C/C++ compiler is a little less necessary but will barely take any space (their primary libs have to be there anyway) and don't do anything when not in use.  AFAIK there aren't any programming interfaces worth removing from stock Raspbian except that Wolfram math thing (if it is still stock).

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to remove any packages that you do not require with the command `sudo apt-get purge <PackageName>`. The system should then offer to remove other packages that will not be needed.
It is not adviseable to only update some packages that are installed and not others since most packages depend on other packages being at a certain version date.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is misguided. "Programming" actually contributes very little to upgrades which, in any event, are quite modest in size.

The other answers have pointed out the folly of selective updates. If you want to minimise the size of your image un-install unwanted applications (there are quite a few in Raspbian which would fall into this category). This will prevent the upgrades from installing. `Python` and `perl` do NOT fall into this category.

The simplest answer, if you are concerned about data usage, is **DO NOT UPDATE/UPGRADE**. There is **no need** to do so - your system will continue to operate. Upgrades tend to add new features and fix bugs, but unless you have a problem DO NOTHING.